# How do I pop an element in an 3D-list?

Tags: python, list

I have this 3D-list:
`array = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]`

When I want to print a specific element, for example with:
`print(array[1][1][1])`
I would get `h`.

But as soon as I want to pop this element with `array.pop([1][1][1])`, I just get an IndexError: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 2):

Function `pop` works only on 1D lists and takes only one parameter which is position of element that you want to pop so, first, you have to navigate to 1D list from which you want to pop element and then pop element from that list.

```
array[1][1].pop()
print(array) # [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `array[1][1].pop(1)`. `pop` only takes one argument, the position of the element to pop. The reason why your code was crashing is because you had `[1]`, a one element list, and tried to access the second element with `[1][1]`.

Comment: note: 1 refers to the second element. 0 is the first.

Answer (score 0):

this a example

```py
array = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]
# I want pop 'b'
array[0][0].pop(1)
# Out: 'b'
array
# Out: [[['a'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]
```

I hope I can help you (*￣︶￣)